# Retrieving a FB Fan Page Access-Token

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a situation where I have to post a photo to a fan page via FB Canvas Application. My problem is that I only managed to post successfully being a page administrator. Is there some way any other normal user can retrieve the fan-page access_token and post successfully?

Url I am calling to retrieve FanPage access_tokens:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=[user-access_token]
```

I am setting the following permissions :

```
email,read_stream,publish_stream,user_photos,photo_upload,manage_pages,offline_access
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve should work with an **[offline access token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602073/access-public-graph-api-resources-with-app-facebook/6602207#6602207)** for your page administrator.

Comment: Not working, requires a FULL active access_token for the resource (/me/accounts) . thanks anyway

Comment: did you specify all required permissions while creating that offline access token? this token will be **active** as long as you don't take away permissions or change password!

Comment: Yeah I did, set all permissions user parameter 'scope', and never changed a password, no difference... do you have any other idea? Thanks again.

Comment: Since you want a user to post on a page where you are admin of, you need an access token from that administrator that never expires. This is the only solution I can think ok.

Comment: Awesome idea... Can you give me some direction how to set an "never ending" token? Thanks man

Comment: Thats what I ment with the offline access token for your page administrator :) After creating it (with the steps explained in the link) you get a never expiring access token (except for changing password/taking away permissions again) for your admin. This is the access token you can use in your application.

Comment: @MarcUberstein let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1360/discussion-between-sascha-galley-and-marc-uberstein)