# how to get an access code when a facebook user is not involved

Tags: facebook

I am the owner of a facebook like page. I want to grab the news feed using php and output it on my website. I know that I can do this using a valid access token:

https://graph.facebook.com/my_app_id_here/feed?access_token=My_access_token_here

Problem access tokens expire so I know I need to authenticate periodically to get a new access token.

This is where the problem and confusion arises for me. When I read the authentication guide in the facebook dev docs all it talks about is first authenticating the user to get a authorization code from the user and then authenticating the app using the app secret, app id and auth code fromthe user. But this doesn't apply to my situation - I never have a authorization code form the user - all I'm trying to do is access the feed from a php script running on my server....a user is never involved.

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are the owner of the like page, I guess you are also the administrator. What you can do in this case is create an **offline access token** for this (and only for that) user.

You can then use this access token for your script. No user needs to authenticate anything if you only want to grab the feed of your page with the access token of your administrator.

This token never expires except for changing the user's password or taking away permissions again. Look at **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602073/access-public-graph-api-resources-with-app-facebook/6602207#6602207)** to see how to create such an offline access token!

Comment: YESYESYESYESYESYES! There is one line for this in the documentation. I think facebook api docs are amongst the worst I have ever had to use :( Many thanks for the answer Sascha.

Comment: You are more than welcome! Took me some time to figure that out too!

Answer (score 2):

User has to approve your application only once, and later use they can just access your app and use it without approving

Comment: But there isn't any user. Just a php script calling that page. Is this not possible without a user visiting the page, getting the login popup and logging in? Even though I'm not trying to get any info from their page - just my own like page?

Comment: Please specify what are you trying to obtain and from who little bit more. thanks

Comment: I'm trying to obtain the news feed from a like page...like this http://www.facebook.com/financialtimes . Now I'm an admin on this page so I've got the app secret and app id but I don't think I can get an access token without getting the users permission. IS this correct?

Comment: it's strange as it's just application. You should be able to access that feed ...

Answer (score 0):

It seems `offline_access` is no longer available. Now you only get a short-lived `access_token` and you can ask for a long lived one, which is also renewable. You can't get a permanent one though.