# Problem access graph api with some facebook page id/username

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I have successfully made an facebook application which shows real time data from facebook graph api with no authentication. The method i have used is something the simple connection to the graph api because i only need the basic info for it.

```
    $url = 'http://graph.facebook.com/'.$pagename;
    // for id
    $url = 'http://graph.facebook.com/'.$page_id;
    $pageinfo = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
```

This methord works fine but not for some pages in facebook. My client has send those pages url to me. From my pc but can't access those page (facebook redirects me to the homepage). Also i have tried to access the graph via those page username and id. Its just returning `false`.

Here are those pages. **Note** that not all pages but a few has this problem:

https://www.facebook.com/MontanaDaleCarnegie

https://www.facebook.com/pages/The-Painted-Swan-Online-Marketing/223492000998546

I can't find the issue why these pages aren't accessible. Is there any settings in the page settings page that make the page nonpublic or inaccessible via graph api? The client saying that he can access these pages.

I need your experience an input to overcome this situation. Thanks!

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/6843796

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently if any page has privacy setting restricted the page info can't be access in public.

There is couple of cases:

1. If the page is restricted to any country.
2. If the page has any age restriction. Selected anything other then Anyone (13+)

[image]

You might find it helpfull http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=18162 Check comment #3.

Comment: This is not true, those settings do not affect the graph api.  It has to do with being public.

Comment: those are visibility options so if its age restricted or country restricted. They wont show up.

Comment: Thats not true, I just tested this.  I have age and country and it still works.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to take a look at your two examples and both take me back to the home screen. This certainly means that those pages are not publicly available.

> Is there any settings in the page settings page that make the page
>   nonpublic or inaccessible via graph api?

Yes: In the page settings under "manage permissions" there is a checkbox for "page visibility":

> Only admins can see this page

If this is checkbox is selected, neither a user on facebook nor the graph api have access to it. The only possibility would be (but I'm not sure) to use an [offline access token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602073/access-public-graph-api-resources-with-app-facebook/6602207#6602207) from one of the admins.

Comment: Can you see the pages when click them? Its always redirects me to the home.php page of facebook.

Comment: no, I am also redirected to the homescreen (as I mentioned), and the problem is certainly the page visibility setting.