# How do I get “any valid access_token” for reading public posts?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to show the newest 5 posts from my facebook application, and I need to avoid running any server-side code. The following worked until this morning:

```
var id = myappid;
var limit = 5;
var div = document.getElementById('facebook_posts');
FB.init();
FB.api('/'+id+'/posts', {'limit': limit}, function(response) {
if (response && response.data && response.data.length) {
    div.innerHTML = '';
    for (var i=0, l=response.data.length; i<l; i++) {
        var post = response.data[i];
        if (post.message && post.link)
            div.innerHTML += '<a href="' + post.link + '">' + post.message + '</a><br/>';
        }
    } else {
        div.innerHTML = 'Error loading facebook posts';
    }
});
```

I didn't change anything, but now facebook returns an "OAuthException" with the message "An access token is required to request this resource.". [The API says](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/) I need "Any valid access_token to see public". So, how do I get "Any valid access_token" without showing an authendication pop-up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing would be to use an offline access token created for your administrator user. [Look here to find out how to create one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602073/access-public-graph-api-resources-with-app-facebook/6602207#6602207).

Comment: Do note that if you do this you'll need to embed that access token in the web page, which will allow anyone with access to the web page to see it, copy it and reuse it. You may not have a problem with this, but its something to note and be careful that you do not grant the token any permission to change things, particularly since you expressly intend to avoid server side programming.

Comment: Unfortunately, [offline-access tokens were deprecated](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/), so you probably have to look into something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the token that the Facebook graph API explorer uses.  But don't grab one from your personal account if you are embedding the token in your page.

Comment: Does this still work? To me it looks like the Graph API Explorer now also requires you to request a short-lived access token associated with your user account.